# NodeJS - Create a object in the session

Tags: node.js, session

I am trying to create an object and store it in the session in order to access it everywhere.

Require:

```
var session = require('express-session');
```

In app.js:

```
app.use(session({
    secret: '1234567890poiuytrewq1234567890-.,',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));
app.use(function(req, res, next){
   if(!req.session.auth){
       req.session.auth = new AuthService();
   }
   next();
});
```

If I `console.log(req.session.auth)` then the object is OK. But if I go to a route the object is not there:

```
router.post('/login', function(req, res){
    if(req.body.remember){
        //I'll do this later
    }
    var username = req.body.username;
    var cryptPass = md5(req.body.password);
    res.send(req.session.auth);
});
```

I am new to NodeJS, what I am doing wrong handling sessions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`express-session` serialize session data using `JSON.stringify` so u can't hold instances of complex objects in session. Serialization will remove all object methods.

Comment: Oh, thats so bad. Thanks for your help a lot, you solved a lot of time testing. Is possible what I am trying?

Comment: If this `AuthService` support some kind of restore, yes

Comment: What are you meaning with some kind of restore?